# How to send data to custom stream IP from memory through DMA in Xilinx SDK?

Tags: sdk, embedded, fpga, xilinx, zynq

I have created two custom stream IO in Vivado HLS by following this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3So1DPe2_4s, concat and slice ips.

I created block design following this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R8MSpEU7UKE.

I want to send data from Zynq PS to my IPS through AXI DMA, and then I want to write the same data to DDR in Zynq PS. How can I do that in Xilinx SDK?
[My_Block_Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ybkLF.png)

Comment: I have rephrased your question to try to save it.  Starting _"Is there a resource..."_ instantly disqualifies the question as off-topic on SO.  Instead explain what you are trying to do, then ask about how to do it including any relevant code or other information you have you already have.  You might try to couch your question too without relying on links to YouTube - no one is going to spend the time to go through them and the links may stale.  If you have a block design, include it in the question perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

It's quite a general question. Without more information about your specific problem..

Have you read the DMA product guide? (**PG021 document from Xilinx**).
It describes how to use that IP Core, including section '**Example Design**', '**Design flow steps**' and 'designing with the core'